# Navigating in DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I am trying to extract some data out of an e-commerce website for analysis. I use the `DOMDocument()` method but I can't manage to reach the price (9.90€) and the product name (Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits).

The following code is 24 times in the same page on which I previously did a:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page2);
```

What would be the DOM path to get the price and the product name?

```html
        <div
  id="product-138156"
  class="blockProduct"
  onmouseover="javascript:layoverShow('138156');"
  onmouseout="javascript:layoverHide('138156');"
>
  <div
    class="block-product-hover"
    id="product-hover-138156"
    style="display: none;"
  >
    <div class="block-product-hover-shadow-top png_fix"></div>
    <div class="block-product-hover-shadow-bg png_fix">
      <div class="picture">
        <div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:9999;position:relative;">
          <a
            class="cloud-zoom"
            href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm"
            rel="'bigImage': '/images/cache//e/3/-e3c5743524d99741099da77a3dff9789_w310_h310.jpg'"
            style="position: relative; display: block;"
          >
            <img
              title="Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits"
              alt="Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits"
              src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//e/3/-e3c5743524d99741099da77a3dff9789_w170_h170.jpg"
              height="170"
              width="170"
              aptsrc="/images/blank.gif"
              style="display: block;"
            />
          </a>
          <div
            class="mousetrap"
            style="background-image:url(/images/blank.gif);z-index:999;position:absolute;width:170px;height:170px;left:0px;top:0px;"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <h3>
          <a
            href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm"
            >Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits</a
          >
        </h3>

        <div
          class="starBlock_s"
          itemscope=""
          itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate"
        ></div>
        <div class="action">
          <div>
            <span class="availability">En stock</span>
            <strong>9,90&nbsp;€</strong>
          </div>

          <a
            onclick="add_cart_liste_product('MTM4MTU2','MTM4MTU2','0.18722700 1388075230','MTM4MTU2','FR','fr','00000190',1); return wasaTrack('',this,200,function(data,link){ _gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', data.category, data.action ]);}, { 'category': 'AjoutPanier', 'action': 'Listes' })"
            class="btn-cart png_fix"
            >Ajouter au panier</a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        <p>Hauteur : 1.6 cm <br />Largeur : 4.7 cm <br />Profondeur : cm</p>
        <span class="hr">&nbsp;</span>
        <p>
          <a
            href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm"
            >Transformez votre intérieur avec nos objets Déco Maisons du
            Monde.</a
          >
        </p>
        <p>
          <a
            class="more"
            href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm"
            >En savoir +</a
          >
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block-product-hover-shadow-bottom png_fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="picture">
    <a href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm">
      <img
        title="Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits"
        alt="Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits"
        src="http://cdn.maisonsdumonde.com//images/cache//e/3/-e3c5743524d99741099da77a3dff9789_w170_h170.jpg"
        height="170"
        width="170"
        aptsrc="/images/blank.gif"
      />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h3>
      <a href="/FR/fr/produits/fiche/coffret-bougies-ptits-biscuits-138156.htm"
        >Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits</a
      >
    </h3>

    <div
      class="starBlock_s"
      itemscope=""
      itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate"
    ></div>
    <div class="action">
      <p>
        <span class="availability">En stock</span>
        <strong>9,90&nbsp;€</strong>
      </p>

      <a
        onclick="add_cart_liste_product('MTM4MTU2','MTM4MTU2','0.22488000 1388075230','MTM4MTU2','FR','fr','00000190',1); return wasaTrack('',this,200,function(data,link){ _gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', data.category, data.action ]);}, { 'category': 'AjoutPanier', 'action': 'Listes' })"
        class="btn-cart png_fix"
        >Ajouter au panier</a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information I finally used :

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "",str_replace(",",".",substr($linker->nodeValue, 0, -5)))
```

Answer (score 2):

They seems to be isolated to `<strong>`-tags, and those are the only `<strong>`-tags there is :

```
$html = file_get_contents('path-to-document.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$strong = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strong');
foreach ($strong as $price) {
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $price->nodeValue, $match);
    echo $match[0][0].'.'.$match[0][1].'<br>';
}
```

..echoes 9.90 twice

---

**Update**
Regarding productName, again you can

```
$h3 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach ($h3 as $product) {
    echo $product->nodeValue;
}
```

The output will be "`Coffret bougies P'tits biscuits`" in plain text, the `<a>`-tag is ignored; and in the above loop even :

```
$product->nodeValue='new product name';
```

Since the whole product / HTML snippet is in a DOM-object, the new value is stored and "new product name" is shown if you run the loop again. Export it with :

```
$dom->save($filename)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for the price. Now I need to get the corresponding product names :)

Comment: Now I'll try to duplicate/modify it for the product names.

Comment: @justberare - did you manage to manipulate the productName? See update.

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample data, this works for me using [`DOMDocument()`](http://php.net/domdocument) and [`DOMXPath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). I simply took your sample data & placed it in a file called `test.html`:

```
// Get the contents of the HTML file & load it into a variable.
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

// Parse the HTML with 'DOMDocument()'
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Parse the DOM with 'DOMXPath()'
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Do an xpath query for a <strong> tag which must be nested in a <div> that has a <span> with the class being 'availability'
$resource = $xpath->query("//div/span[@class='availability']/..//strong")->item(0);

// The text content in the <strong> tag which must be nested in a <div> that has a <span> with the class being 'availability'
echo $resource->textContent;

// Dump the contents of '$resource' for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resource);
echo '<pre>';
```

The magic here is the query of:

```
//div/span[@class='availability']/..//strong
```

Which basically reads as follows:

```
//div/span[@class='availability']
```

That part means simply find a  that has a  with the class being 'availability'.  Then the next part:

```
/..
```

Simply go up one level in the node—similar to a directory path in Unix—and then do this:

```
//strong
```

Now find the  tag.

Which is where the price is located. [`DOMDocument()`](http://php.net/domdocument) and [`DOMXPath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) can seem daunting at times, but once you understand the basic syntax it’s a very nice tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailled answer. I'll use it for the product name. (I already put the 24 prices in an array, I just need to do the same with the product names).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about DOM but

```
// $page2 should have the page html
preg_match("/(\d+,\d{2})&nbsp;€/",$page2, $matches);
$price = $matches[1];
```

Comment: I am trying to use your solution for the product names but this generates an error :  preg_match_all('/<div\sclass=\"details\">/<h3>/<a\shref=\".*\">.*/<\/a>/', $page2, $matcher);
 echo $matcher[5];   I just went through the regular expression doc but I can't find the solution. Thanks again for your support.